# If $A$ is a fractional ideal of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-m})$, then $A^{1+\sigma}$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: number-theory, ideal-class-group

I'm stuck on this little detail in Washington's intro to cyclotomic fields.

Let $M = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-m})$, and $A$ be a fractional ideal of $M$.  With $Gal(M/\mathbb{Q})= \{1,\sigma\}$, Washington says that $A^{1 + \sigma} = A\cdot A^{\sigma}$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Q}$.  I'm a little confused, but I think what he means is that $A^{1+\sigma} = q\mathcal{O}_M$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ (the point of this is to show that $A^{1+\sigma}$ is principal).

With $A = \alpha I$ for some ideal $I$ in $\mathcal{O}_M$ and $\alpha \in M$, we have
\begin{align*}
A^{1+\sigma} = \alpha\overline{\alpha}(I\cdot I^{\sigma})
\end{align*}
and $\alpha\overline{\alpha} \in \mathbb{Q}$.  I guess it then comes down to showing that $I\cdot I^{\sigma}$ is principal (not sure if this would even be true).

Is this the right interpretation?

Comment: Yes, but remember that $A$ need not be principal, so this is non-trivial.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yeah, I had $m = 5$ and $I = 3\mathcal{O}_M + (1 + \sqrt{-5})\mathcal{O}_M$ floating around in my head.  I was hoping that multiplying $I$ with $I^{\sigma}$ magically gives you something principle.  Guess I just need to look at it some more.

Comment: Friendly but pedantic comment: it is "principal", not "principle".

Comment: You need to make clear that we want $A$ to be a fractional ideal of $O_K$ which means $A = \frac{I}{c}$ for some $c \in O_K$ and some ideal $I$ of $O_K$, in there we have the unique factorization in prime ideals $I = \prod_j \mathfrak{p}_j$ and it suffices to show that $\mathfrak{p}_j\mathfrak{p}_j^\sigma$ is always principal, which is obvious from $(p)$ is a prime  ideal or $(p) = (p,\tau-a)(p,\sigma(\tau)-a)$ where $O_K=\Bbb{Z}[\tau]= \Bbb{Z}[x]/(f(x))$ and $a \in \Bbb{Z}$ is a root of $f \bmod p$

Comment: @reuns I see it now.  If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime in $\mathcal{O}_K$ sitting above $p$, then $p\mathcal{O}_K = \mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{p}^{\sigma}$, or $p\mathcal{O}_K = \mathfrak{p}= \mathfrak{p}^{\sigma}$.  In either case, $\mathfrak{p}\mathfrak{p}^{\sigma}$ is principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT after discussion with the* OP.

I keep your hypotheses, with the additional notations $I,J$,etc. for integral ideals, i.e. ideals of the ring of integers $S$ of $M$. Write also $N$ for the usual norm map of $M/\mathbf Q$. The absolute norm $N(I)$ (there will be no confusion with the notation) is classically defined as card $(S/I)$ up to a sign. As $\pm 1$ are the only units of $\mathbf Z$, we may as well view $N(I)$ as an ideal of $\mathbf Z$, and extend it to *S* by considering the ideal $N(I).S$. Define also the ideal $\nu(I)=I.\sigma(I)$ of *S*. To stress the difference, $N(I)$ (resp. $\nu(I)$) is sometimes called the arithmetic (resp. algebraic) norm of *I*. You want to show that $\nu(I)=N(I).S$, hence in particular is principal. *Proof*. Since *S* is a Dedekind ring, the question is brought back to the case where $I$ is a prime ideal $P$ of $S$. Let $p$ be the prime number under $P$. There are 3 types of decomposition of $p$ in $S$ : $p$ is inert, i.e. $pS$ is prime; $p$ splits, i.e. $pS=P.\sigma(P)$; $p$ is (totally) ramified, i.e. $pS=P^2$ (you seem to have forgotten this last possibility in your reply to @reuns). The norm calculations relative to these distinct cases can be synthetized in the single formula $N(P)=p^f$, where $f=f(P/p)$ is the inertia index of $P$ over $p$. This also gives $N(P).S$, which can be checked to be equal to $P.\sigma(P)$ using the decomposition of $p$ in $S$.

I gave all the (ponderous) details because this approach can be directly extended to an arbitrary finite Galois extension of number fields $M/K$ with Galois group $G$. (**NB**: this is not merely generalization for the sake of generalization. The norm of ideals is an essential tool in class field theory.) Let $R,S$ resp. be the ring of integers of $K,M$. The point is the definition of the arithmetic norm $N(I)$. There are many equivalent definitions, but the equivalence is sometimes not quite straightforward. See e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9235/a-problem-on-algebraic-number-theory-norm-of-ideals. Following D. Marcus, "Number Fields", chapter 3, define $\nu(I)= \prod \sigma I$, for all $\sigma \in G$, and $N(I)=R \cap \nu(I)$. Then it can be shown along our previous line (but of course in a more complicated way) that $N(I).S=\nu(I)$. For details, see *op. cit.* chapter 3, exercise 14.

Comment: You're quite right, I showed only an inclusion. Sorry for my carelessness, I'll edit my answer.